# Deploying node js app on heroku gives error

Tags: node.js, heroku

This is the log I get from running `heroku logs --tail`

```
2022-08-10T15:46:34.923072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-10T15:46:36.618392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-10T15:46:38.505658+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-10T15:46:38.505695+00:00 app[web.1]: > fandom-fetch@1.0.0 start
2022-08-10T15:46:38.506098+00:00 app[web.1]: > index.js
2022-08-10T15:46:38.506098+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-10T15:46:38.511467+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: index.js: not found
2022-08-10T15:46:38.665217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-08-10T15:46:38.731469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-10T15:46:57.417977+00:00 app[api]: Stack changed from heroku-20 to heroku-22 by user suneradrck@gmail.com
2022-08-10T15:48:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user suneradrck@gmail.com
2022-08-10T15:48:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-10T15:48:54.455105+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 75289dfb by user suneradrck@gmail.com
2022-08-10T15:48:54.455105+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user suneradrck@gmail.com
2022-08-10T15:48:54.718566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-10T15:48:56.635960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-10T15:48:59.157726+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-10T15:48:59.157739+00:00 app[web.1]: > fandom-fetch@1.0.0 start
2022-08-10T15:48:59.157739+00:00 app[web.1]: > index.js
2022-08-10T15:48:59.157740+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-10T15:48:59.165066+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: index.js: not found
2022-08-10T15:48:59.318731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-08-10T15:48:59.455664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-10T15:48:59.458782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-10T15:49:01.257931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-10T15:49:03.132571+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-10T15:49:03.132583+00:00 app[web.1]: > fandom-fetch@1.0.0 start
2022-08-10T15:49:03.132583+00:00 app[web.1]: > index.js
2022-08-10T15:49:03.132583+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-10T15:49:03.142956+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: index.js: not found
2022-08-10T15:49:03.267249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-08-10T15:49:03.330712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

As it says it seems that index.js is missing but I surely have it in the repo that I pushed... I don't know what's going on.

Update: so I logged in to heroku bash and uses ls command. It seems index.js is present.

```
~ $ ls
LICENSE  README.md  index.js  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  test.js
```

still giving that error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start` script needs to include the full command to run, not just the name of your main file:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Comment: ok thank you very much... It runs in the local mode... that's why I got confused.

Comment: No i mean the `heroku web local` command. It worked fine. `npm start` also worked without using the node at the begining.

Comment: Are you on Windows? It might have an OS-level association between `.js` files and Node.js, but that is definitely not a standard feature. When you "run" a file like this you need to actually run Node.js and pass the file as an argument.